# Angular - redirecting to another component and reading value from a subject

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've an app that shows a grid view of messages a user has received, very similar to an inbox. When a user clicks one of the messages the detail of the message appears on screen (over the grid, there's no routing involved), they can click to close it to view the grid again.

I also have a search component which will display search results, one of these results might be a message. If the user clicks the message in the search results, they get redirected to the message component and the message in question opens as per the above paragraph.

If I use a subject and then redirect the user I believe the value in the subject will be lost. Does my scenario sound like a good example of when I should use a behavior subject?

So the flow would be - user clicks search result (message) behavior subject populated, user redirected to message view. Message component checks if the user came from the search results page, if so then check the behavior subject for the last emitted value and show the detail on screen.

Is this the correct use of a behavior subject?

Comment: You are right. A behaviour subject stores something until the page gets completly reloaded. The best way to serve your data in this case is to use the behaviour subject in a service.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it sounded right but wanted to be sure.

Comment: @JuNe are we talking about RxJs's [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html) ? It has nothing to do with page reloading. It is just a subject that emits its last value to new subscribers. But it would actually fit the need. Maybe a more "natural" way of doing it is using route params.

Comment: you can try to combine `Subject` and `scan` operator but in general `RelaySubject` should do the trick - all the previous messages will be emitted on every new subscribe

Comment: @YevheniiDovhaniuk thanks, hadn't considered a relay subject - I'll check it out.

Comment: It's actually `ReplaySubject`, I've done a typo mistake over there. https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/replaysubject.html or https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/class/ReplaySubject